# Passing intent extras from a google cloud message receiver to activity is null

Tags: android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging, android-broadcast

I have a broadcast receiver that listens for cloud messages, I can display the notification fine but when the user clicks the notification I want to route them to the proper activity with intent extras. The extras are always null.

I can verify that the intent passed to pending intent does have extras while debugging.

I try to pick up on the intents in the activites onCreate() method

***EDIT adding working code, there are a few things to note, you can not count on the oncreate() method to be called if the task is already started so it seems to best place to get the extras is in the onresume method. I needed to set the flags on the intent and on the pending intent

```
@EReceiver
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "googlecloudmessage";
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
private NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
private Context ctx;

@Pref
public MyPrefs_ myPrefs;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.d(TAG, "received gcm message");

    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
    this.ctx = context;

    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (messageType != null) {

        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {

        }
        else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {

        }
        else if (messageType.equalsIgnoreCase("gcm")) {
            myPrefs.notification().put(true);
            handleNotification(intent);
        }
    }
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}

private void handleNotification(Intent intent) {

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    String typeString = bundle.getString("type");
    String icon = bundle.getString("icon");

    String title = null;
    String body = null;
    Class<?> intentClass = null;
    Integer intentExtraId = null;

    if (typeString == null)
        return;

    int type = Integer.parseInt(typeString);

    switch (type) {

    case 1:

        intentClass = FriendsActivity_.class;

        title = bundle.getString("username");

        break;

    case 2:

        intentClass = UserProfileActivity_.class;

        title = bundle.getString("username");

        intentExtraId = Integer.parseInt(bundle.getString("user_id"));

        break;




    }


    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClass(ctx, intentClass);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP     | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    i.putExtra("gcm", true);
    if (intentExtraId != null) {

        i.putExtra("id", intentExtraId);
    }

    int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, requestID, i,     PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);

    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_u);

    Bitmap bmp = null;

    try {
        bmp = Ion.with(ctx, ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.image_container) + icon).asBitmap().get();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ExecutionException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (icon != null) {
        mBuilder.setLargeIcon(bmp);
    }

    mBuilder.setContentTitle(title).setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(body))
            .setContentText(body);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

}
```

}

Activity

```
 @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    Integer newId = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");

    id = newId;


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the call you use to get the `PendingIntent`:

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, i, 0);
```

If there is already a matching `PendingIntent` in the system, this call will just return that one. It may or may not contain the extras you want. To ensure that your extras are used you must ensure that you update any current `PendingIntent`, like this:

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Hi David thanks for your response, Adding that flag to the pending intent does send the extras but I can only pick them up in onresume or onstart, but not oncreate where I normally get the extras, this seems like odd behavior any idea why this happens?

Comment: Post your manifest and I'll have a look. Also post the code you use to get the extras in `onCreate()`

Answer (score 1):

You make simple notiification. And set onclick on this. Paste your activity in the place of YourMainActivity in below example

```
public void createNotification(Context context, String payload, String message) {
    try {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, message, System.currentTimeMillis());
        // Hide the notification after its selected
        // notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.ledARGB = 0xff00ff00;
        notification.ledOnMS = 300;
        notification.ledOffMS = 1000;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourMainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("payload", payload);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("NotifID", 1);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
        PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Message", message, pendingIntent);
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage(), e);

    }
}
```

mark true or vote up if helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this. It is: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String message = data.getString("message");
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
    Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);

    if (from.startsWith("/topics/")) {
        // message received from some topic.
        sendNotification(message)
    } else {
        // normal downstream message.
    }

    // ...
}
```

///////// Add this method

```
private void sendNotification(String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListLocations.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_park_notification)
            .setContentTitle("Parkuest Message")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```